# MySQL Workbench: how to set constraints for certain attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, certain attributes must only be set to certain values. For example, an attribute "status" can only be set to full-time, part-time, or temporary. How and where do I enforce this in MySQL Workbench? (as you can probably tell, I'm very new to MySQL)

Comment: Mysqlworkbench is just a GUI, it does not enforce anything. The mysql server can enforce certain rules as described by Gordon below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in several ways.  The least desirable way would be to set up a trigger.  Another way is to define them as enumerated types.  I'm not really a fan of enumerated types, because they are not easily shared among different tables.

You can also do this with a reference table and a foreign key constraint:

```
create table ReferenceStatus (
    status varchar(255) primary key
);

alter table t add constraint fk_t_status foreign key (status) references ReferenceStatus(status);
```

Comment: Thanks, ENUM was what I was looking for!